# Angular : Getting "No component factory" error while opening a Material Dialog in lazy loaded Component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-material2, mddialog, angular5

Im getting the following error when i try to open Material Dialog in ConfirmBoxComponent.

No component factory found for ConfirmBoxComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
I have already added ConfirmBoxComponent in entryComponents list

```
declarations: [
  ConfirmBoxComponent
],
exports: [ConfirmBoxComponent],
entryComponents: [
  ConfirmBoxComponent
],
```

The module that contain ConfirmBoxComponent is loaded via Lazy loading technique.

I'm using latest version of Angular and Material

"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0"

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I imported MatDialogModule into my lazy loaded module, but still used MatDialog instance from root module, because MatDialog was injected into my own DialogService, which is provided in root module. When I use correct MatDialog instance, from lazy loaded module, there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed. 
I forgot to import  **MatDialogModule** in my lazy loaded module.